# Read attribute from XML in SSMS using XML.Node

Tags: xml, ssms, xmlnode

I'm trying to read an XML file, the aim is to get ddscontrol to return

```
888
```

in one record
and

```
999
```

in the other.

Similarly for tooltip I need to return

```
TTT111
```

and

```
TTT222
```

I can't seem to go deeper beyond dds though for some reason, here's a simplified script to run in SSMS:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML = '
<Create xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
    <ObjectDefinition>
        <Database>
            <ID>White Stuff BI OLAP Solution</ID>
            <Dimensions>
                <Dimension>
                    <ID>Dim Dynamic Date Filter</ID>
                    <Annotations>
                        <Annotation>
                            <Name>http://schemas.microsoft.com/DataWarehouse/Designer/1.0:DiagramLayout</Name>
                            <Value>
                                <dds xmlns="this is an XML namespace">123
                                    <ddscontrol tooltip="TTT111">888</ddscontrol></dds>
                            abc</Value>
                        </Annotation>
                        <Annotation>
                            <Name>http://schemas.microsoft.com/DataWarehouse/Designer/1.0:DiagramLayout</Name>
                            <Value>
                                <dds xmlns="this is an XML namespace">456
                                    <ddscontrol tooltip="TTT222">999</ddscontrol></dds>
                            abc</Value>
                        </Annotation>
                    </Annotations>
                </Dimension>
            </Dimensions>
        </Database>
    </ObjectDefinition>
</Create>'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES 
(
    DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine',
    'this is an XML namespace' AS ns2
                      
)


SELECT 
    a.value('(../../../../ID/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as [First ID]
    ,a.value('(../../ID/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as [Second ID]
    ,a.value('(Name/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(1000)') as [Name]
    ,a.value('(Value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(1000)') as [Value]
    ,a.value('(Value/ns2:dds/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(1000)') as [dds]
    ,a.value('(Value/ns2:dds/ddscontrol/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(1000)') as [ddscontrol]
    ,a.value('(Value/ns2:dds/ddscontrol/@tooltip)[1]', 'nvarchar(1000)') as [tooltip]

FROM @XML.nodes('/Create/ObjectDefinition/Database/Dimensions/Dimension/Annotations/Annotation') as x1(a)
```

Result in SSMS:
[image]

Comment: That XML doesn't look right. You have (without the line breaks and whitespace): `<Value><dds xmlns="ANSWER!!!">123</dds>abc</Value>` `Value` should include a value or more nodes; not both.

Comment: `xmlns` is not attribute. It is namespace declaration.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Larnu already mentioned, the XML doesn't look right.

Please try the following solution.

Notable points:

- It is using two namespace declarations.
- It is better NOT to traverse XML up.
- `../text()` is added to XPath expressions for performance reasons.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml AS XML = 
N'<Create xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
    <ObjectDefinition>
        <Database>
            <ID>White Stuff BI OLAP Solution</ID>
            <Dimensions>
                <Dimension>
                    <ID>Dim Dynamic Date Filter</ID>
                    <Annotations>
                        <Annotation>
                            <Name>http://schemas.microsoft.com/DataWarehouse/Designer/1.0:DiagramLayout</Name>
                            <Value>
                                <dds xmlns="this is an XML namespace">123
                                    <ddscontrol tooltip="TTT111">888</ddscontrol>
                                </dds>abc</Value>
                        </Annotation>
                        <Annotation>
                            <Name>http://schemas.microsoft.com/DataWarehouse/Designer/1.0:DiagramLayout</Name>
                            <Value>
                                <dds xmlns="this is an XML namespace">456
                                    <ddscontrol tooltip="TTT222">999</ddscontrol>
                                </dds>abc</Value>
                        </Annotation>
                    </Annotations>
                </Dimension>
            </Dimensions>
        </Database>
    </ObjectDefinition>
</Create>';

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES 
(
    DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine',
    'this is an XML namespace' AS ns2
)
SELECT a.value('(ID/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as [First ID]
    ,a.value('(Dimensions/Dimension/ID/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as [Second ID]
    ,b.value('(Name/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(1000)') as [Name]
    ,b.value('(Value/ns2:dds/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(1000)') as [dds]
    ,b.value('(Value/ns2:dds/ns2:ddscontrol/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(1000)') as ddscontrol
    ,b.value('(Value/ns2:dds/ns2:ddscontrol/@tooltip)[1]', 'nvarchar(1000)') as tooltip
FROM @xml.nodes('/Create/ObjectDefinition/Database') as t1(a)
    CROSS APPLY t1.a.nodes('Dimensions/Dimension/Annotations/Annotation') AS t2(b);
```

Comment: Thanks @Yitzhak Khabinsky, I've just modified the question slightly to reflect what is hopefully now a correct XML, would you be able to assist please?

Comment: Also, please up-vote my suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/153a9604-7025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

Comment: Thanks again, is it not possible to use to `FROM @XML.nodes('/Create/ObjectDefinition/Database/Dimensions/Dimension/Annotations/Annotation') as x1(a)` like before though?  because right now I'm not able to see all annotation in case more than 1 of them appears

Comment: I added a comment for your original question. Check it out.

Comment: ok thanks, I've edited my question once again.  But basically your last solution was fine except when more than 1 annotation appears, which I've added an example to the question.

Comment: Would this be slower or quicker
`
SELECT b.value('(../../../../ID/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as [First ID]
    ,b.value('(../../ID/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as [Second ID]
    ,b.value('(Name/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(1000)') as [Name]
    ,b.value('(Value/ns2:dds/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(1000)') as [dds]
    ,b.value('(Value/ns2:dds/ns2:ddscontrol/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(1000)') as ddscontrol
    ,b.value('(Value/ns2:dds/ns2:ddscontrol/@tooltip)[1]', 'nvarchar(1000)') as tooltip
FROM @xml.nodes('/Create/ObjectDefinition/Database/Dimensions/Dimension/Annotations/Annotation') as t1(b)`

Comment: Sorry I couldn't work out how to format the code above, but basically I rewrote it without the outer apply and was just wondering if there's any differnce over performance for a much larger XML file?

Comment: It would be slower because it is traversing XML up axis